# Customize title bar default in android

Tags: android, layout, titlebar

When I create any application, Android always gives me the same title bar. What do I need to do to customize it (background and text)? Maybe change style.xml or change the `onCreate()` method?

I updated AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml:

**@AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.searchmedicinelayout"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.searchmedicinelayout.SearchMedicineActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailMedicine"
            android:label="@string/detail"
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.searchmedicinelayout.SearchMedicineActivity" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**@styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the title of application and the activitys in the AndroidManifest.xml file. You change the values of fields "android:label" with the your custom text. The "@string/app_name" is a label declared in the file "strings" (folder "values" of your projetc). There, you can create or modify new labels.

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name="shooterfugio.aquiniela2.MiApp">
    <activity
        android:name="shooterfugio.aquiniela2.MiTareaAsincrona"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".Aquiniela"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".IntroduceTexto"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Popup1"
        android:label="@string/info"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>  
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
               android:value="@string/applicationId" />
</application>
```

To change the background, you must do it in the file name_activity.xml, as follows:

```
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:background="@drawable/image_background"
              android:id="@+id/main_ui_container">
```

Note: "image_background" is the name of a file with a background image (located in the folder "drawable")

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. I want to change title bar which contain the icon, lable, project name... I only change background and modify text size, text color, text align of it. I don't want show it to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably need to look at your code, but the title bar's title and style are generally defined in the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). More specifically, you want to look at the part that defines your application:

```
<application
 android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/customTheme">
```

Now, to change the title bar's text, you have to go to your strings.xml and edit the value for app_name. If, on the other hand, you want to restyle it, you need to create a [style file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) under res/values/, with some styling xml. For example, the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#1BE032</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#1BE032</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

will make the window look a bit too green-ish.

In any case, it would be helpful to post your AndroidManifest and any custom themes, if you are using any.

Comment: I just want to change background on the title bar and set text center and change size. The AndroidManifest is default when I create project. I have updated 2 file on top.